# Why did the Obelisk affect some characters, but not others?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of SHIELD* S02E10, *What They Become*, we see

> Raina, Skye, and Tripp enter the Temple and are exposed to the contents of the Obelisk, a crystal which blasted out a shockwave of air.

Afterwards, 2 of them are affected, but not Tripp.  Why wasn't he affected, why were

> Raina and Skye coated in stone?

What happened in this scene?  Is this explained by something in the Marvel Comics?

Comment: Opened [a chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19346/agents-of-nothing) for some discussion/clarification (warning: spoilers):

Comment: Are spoiler tags necessary? The show is already several hours old.

Comment: @SachinShekhar *Yes*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my explanation using only information from the show:

> Raina and Skye have both been shown to be "special" by being able to
>  touch the Obelisk.  When it's activated, they're each coated in a
>  material briefly, as if it were a chrysalis.  When they emerge from
>  the stone, they are something Inhuman.

The other half of the situation:

> Tripp, on the other hand, is a normal human.  He isn't "special" by
>  the Obelisk's standards, so he isn't effected by the shockwave. 
>  However, when he smashes the Obelisk in a mistaken attempt to save
>  Skye, the shrapnel from the Obelisk has the same effect that we've
>  seen the Obelisk have on "unworthy" individuals: he's turned to stone, and dies.